# How can I reproduce the output of lightning-cli newaddr?

Tags: address, core-lightning

If I do:

```
lightning-cli newaddr
```

I get an on-chain address I can send funds to. How can I see the same address again, if (for example) the terminal gets closed by accident before I've finished with it?

A motivating example: I do a newaddr and create a transaction to transfer funds to that address. I spend five minutes messing around with my hardware wallet to sign it. Before I actually broadcast the signed transaction, I'd like to double-check the destination address is correct, but it's no longer visible.

As a more general follow-on question: is there any way to see the on-chain addresses for Core Lightning's wallet and their balances? Something a bit like Electrum's "Addresses" tab, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build CLN with the developer options (most likely you did), then you have the `dev-listaddrs` command that you can use to list all addresses that have been generated.

It's a developer only command for now, since the format hasn't been formalized yet, but it has remained stable for quite some time:

https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/blob/f158b529d3e4c56b70c44aaebc821c1f15477fa2/wallet/walletrpc.c#L226-L234

Answer (score 1):

> As a more general follow-on question: is there any way to see the on-chain addresses for Core Lightning's wallet and their balances?

To see the balances, yes, you can. When funds arrive, you will see that balance change. But in terms of the on-chain addresses, no, technically, core-lightning wallet doesn't have that feature AFAIK.

Then, based on your question how do you check the addresses?
Here is something useful.
Here's [a link](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/issues/1762)!

In short, it is different from any common BIP standards implementation.
I encourage you to check that article out and play around with the https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks, that's a really interesting thread!